# mysql how to set "where" condition if the field content is part of searching string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one mysql table `mytable` with below structure and record:

```
| id |    url       |
|----|--------------|
|  1 | article/read |
```

I have searching strings such as

```
'article/read/1/',
'article/read/about',
'article/read/tag/2'
etc..
```

If any string contains the `url` record `article/read`, then it returns the row.

How can I write the MYSQL query string?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I am trying hard to understand what your want to do, can you make your question a little bit more clear?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `url` LIKE 'article/read%'
```

Comment: the string 'article/read%' in your query is not sure.This string comes from my page uri ,it may be article/read/1,article/read/2,or article/read/tag2 etc,but  the `url` of one row contains 'article/read'

Comment: Can you post your codes? It would help us to understand the problem much better. Thanks :)